# How to Enable Facebook Sandbox mode?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-oauth

The documentation and links out there on how to enable Facebook Sandbox mode seem to be out of date.

I don't see the radio button in my **Settings** > **Advanced**.

Even this is different https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/bestpractice/managing-development-cycle/

Comment: It’s on the “Status & Review” tab now and called _“Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?”_ (It’s not so hard IMHO to figure that out if one just looks around a little …)

Comment: Why not make that an answer, @CBroe?

Answer (score 1):

It’s on the *“Status & Review”* tab now and called *“Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?”*